# Loading Google Maps, a weird error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ? in older versions of chrome

Tags: javascript, uncaught-exception

I am getting a weird error in some older versions of chrome, probably 2019 ( I am using an embedded chrome browser )  when I try to load google maps. It does not throw an error in the current versions of chrome.(2020 and onwards is fine)  It has started all of a sudden.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey"></script>
```

js?key=apikey:67 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

I am really curious what might be the error is, can anyone shed light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try ...`js/?key=`, but I don't recall if a trailing slash was required

Comment: @Phix  that did not work unfortunately

Comment: Likely Google doesn’t support that old version of chrome

Comment: Is that an error from the browser or from the server?

Comment: I would have expected a clear message from google if it was not supported anymore. It is an error from the browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the same problem.
I have added "v=3.53" in url to force use an older version of the API.
Google has update API on 18 August 2023. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=...&v=3.53

This solution has solved my problem, I didn't want to update my electron app.
Maybe this solution help you.

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much. Solved the problem magically.

Comment: This will only work as long as that version is available. Any ideas how to fix the problem correctly? Google speaks of "ensure that your applications and web pages proactively include polyfills to allow for ES11-level JavaScript dependencies" [source](https://groups.google.com/g/google-maps-js-api-v3-notify/c/IYXAMIOW3Pw/m/0besxpSKAQAJ?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer)

Comment: Did you find a more permanent solution? I am facing the same problem. I saw that version 3.53 will not be available starting mid-May 2024. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#quarterly-updates

Answer (score 1):

Google map `v=3.53` is good quick fix. It won't work in long term because Google removing older version every quarter.

Current Google map failing in old browser (version 79 or older) because of null coalescing operator (`??`).

`??` It will work Chrome 80 or greater version.